# When to initialize a dummy node in a linked list

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I am implementing a version of singly linked list in Java with a dummy node.

```
public class Node{
  private String data;
  private Node nextNode;
 
  public Node(String data){
    this.data = data;
    this.nextNode = null; 
  }

  //getters, setters, toString()
}

public class LinkedList {
private Node header;
private Node lastNode;
private int size;

public LinkedList() {
    this.header = new Node(null);
    this.lastNode = this.header;
    size = 0;
}

public void prepend(String data) {

    if (data == null || data.trim().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Node newNode = new Node(data);

    // when the linked list is empty
    if (size == 0) {
        this.header.setNext(newNode);
        this.lastNode = newNode;
    } else { // when the list has nodes
        Node existingNode = this.header.getNext();

        newNode.setNext(existingNode);
        this.header.setNext(newNode);
    }
    size++;
}
}
```

I am mainly concentrating on this part.

```
public LinkedList() {
    this.header = new Node(null);
    this.lastNode = this.header;
    size = 0;
}
```

When a linked list object is created and initialized, header and last node point to a dummy node.

Would this be an efficient way to implement a linked list? Or, do I have to alter my code in prepend() method as follows?

```
public void prepend(String data) {

    if (data == null || data.trim().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Node newNode = new Node(data);

    // when the linked list is empty
    if (size == 0) {
        this.header = new Node(null);
        this.header.setNext(newNode);
        this.lastNode = newNode;
    } else { // when the list has nodes
        Node existingNode = this.header.getNext();

        newNode.setNext(existingNode);
        this.header.setNext(newNode);
    }
    size++;
}
```

Also, is it really necessary to use a dummy node as the header? Can we use the first node itself as the header? Under what circumstances should we be using a dummy node, if at all used?

Comment: There is no need for a dummy node. Just initialize `this.header` and `this.lastNode` with `null` (by default, their initial value will be `null`). _"Can we use the first node itself as the header?"_ - yes, AFAIK, that is usually how linked list is implemented. _"Under what circumstances should we be using a dummy node"_ - i can't think of how a dummy node will be useful in a linked list implementation.

Comment: @Yousaf I thought so too. There are a few tutorials which use a dummy node as the header. I am wondering when should it be used and when not? When asked to write code to simulate a linked list in an interview, should I be using a dummy node or not?

Comment: No need for a dummy node. Initial value of `this.header` should be `null` and when the first node is inserted, `this.header` should point to that node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dummy node is useful if you want to enforce a non-`null` constraint for the link fields of the node. Further, it allows to implement all operations without the need to implement special cases for the first and last node, e.g.

```java
public class LinkedList {
    static final Node REMOVED = new Node();

    public static class Node {
        Node next, prev;
        String data;
        Node() {
            next = prev = this;
        }
        Node(String s, Node n, Node p) {
            data = s;
            next = n;
            prev = p;
        }
        public Node insertBefore(String s) {
            if(next == REMOVED) throw new IllegalStateException("removed node");
            Node node = new Node(s, this, prev);
            prev.next = node;
            prev = node;
            return node;
        }
        public Node insertAfter(String s) {
            return next.insertBefore(s);
        }
        public void remove() {
            if(next == REMOVED) throw new IllegalStateException("already removed");
            prev.next = next;
            next.prev = prev;
            next = prev = REMOVED;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    final Node content = new Node();

    private Node first() {
        return content.next;
    }

    private Node last() {
        return content.prev;
    }

    public Node getFirst() {
        Node f = first();
        if(f == content)
            return null; // or throw new NoSuchElementException(string);
        return f;
    }

    public Node getLast() {
        Node f = last();
        if(f == content)
            return null; // or throw new NoSuchElementException(string);
        return f;
    }

    public Node prepend(String s) {
        return first().insertBefore(s);
    }

    public Node append(String s) {
        return last().insertAfter(s);
    }

    public Node findFirst(String string) {
        for(Node n = first(); n != content; n = n.next) {
            if(n.data.equals(string)) return n;
        }
        return null; // or throw new NoSuchElementException(string);
    }

    public Node findLast(String string) {
        for(Node n = last(); n != content; n = n.prev) {
            if(n.data.equals(string)) return n;
        }
        return null; // or throw new NoSuchElementException(string);
    }

    void printForward() {
        for(Node n = first(); n != content; n = n.next) {
            System.out.println(n.data);
        }
    }

    void printBackward() {
        for(Node n = last(); n != content; n = n.prev) {
            System.out.println(n.data);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a doubly linked list whose internally used dummy node’s `next` and `prev` fields become the “first” and “last” fields of the list. This way, all modification methods only have to operate on the `Node` class and its `next` and `prev` fields and the references to the first and last node are treated the right way automatically. Note how all modification methods settle atop only two implementation methods, `insertBefore` and `remove`.

It can be use like

```java
LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
l.append("H").insertAfter("l").insertAfter("l");
l.findFirst("l").insertBefore("e");
l.findLast("l").insertAfter("o");
l.printForward();

System.out.println();

l.getFirst().remove();
l.findFirst("l").remove();
l.getFirst().remove();
l.getLast().insertBefore("r");
l.getFirst().insertBefore("d");
l.append("W");
l.printBackward();
```

for example. For a single linked list, a dummy node might be less useful. If, like in your example, you’re not drawing a benefit from it but have all the special case handling, you should not use a dummy node which only makes the code even more complicated.